# Not able to save file in Sdcard when using 'uses-sdk' in manifest

Tags: android

I am creating an app to record voice, when I try to store file in sdcard with

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

it gives me error "No such file or directory", but when I comment out the "uses-sdk" part from manifest, it is working fine. I am not sure what is the actual problem, but it seems like it is due to setting sdk-version in manifest.
I also tried increasing/decreasing minSdkVersion, but still same error.

Below is the error log.

```
 11-28 15:53:54.887: W/System.err(5935): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Recorder/voicemail.3gp (No such file or directory)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:144)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:540)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at com.abc.SendVoiceMailFragment.startRecording(SendVoiceMailFragment.java:96)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at com.abc.SendVoiceMailFragment.access$0(SendVoiceMailFragment.java:84)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at com.abc.SendVoiceMailFragment$3.onClick(SendVoiceMailFragment.java:59)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-28 15:53:54.897: W/System.err(5935):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT**
Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.abc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="androd.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/tab_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

**My code to create file**

```
private String getFilename(){
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_FILE_NAME + ".3gp");
    }
```

Comment: post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @imrankhan just did. plese check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of doing what you are doing in the manifest is:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" /> <!-- You need a target
```

Also this part should come after the `<uses-sdk>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I dont understand why it gives permission denied error after setting sdkVersion.

Comment: @abhishek - the external storage permission did not exist in the first Android SDK, so is automatically added by subsequent devices when analyzing a package built for an early (or unspecified) SDK version.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have updated my Android SDK to latest version. but still facing the problem.

Comment: The change in question happened years ago, so the solution is not an upgrade but following the present documentation.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am not able to understand.

Comment: @abhishek simply put you NEED android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in order for it to work if you are targeting anything beyond early Android SDK

Comment: @Warpzit I have used android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but here problem is android:minSdkVersion.

Comment: @abishek - no, the problem is still with the external storage permission not being succesfully declared.  When you don't have an SDK version, it assumes the original SDK, and automatically adds the external storage permission which was not part of the original SDK (as a compatibility measure, any app written against the original SDK is assumed by a subsequent device to require external storage)

Comment: @abhishek as Chris said, both target and external permission needs to be declared.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Is there any other way to declare permissions? I mean all other permissions are working just fine. I have shared my manifest file also. Is my order of writing things in manifest right??

Comment: @abhishek have you set target and min in the manifest as well?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I just remove the permission and add it again using permission tab in manifest, Solves the problem.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the folder in which you are storring the file ? (using `mkdirs()`)

Comment: yes I have created the folder as well, check the code above I have just add it over there.